# In JS, how to declare a value for an object and have all parent keys automatically be created?

Tags: javascript

```
myObject = {};

myObject.property1 = "123"
```

Typing `myObject.property1` returns `123`

```
mySecondObject = {};

mySecondObject.property1.value.type.price = "456"
```

returns `TypeError: Cannot set property 'value1' of undefined` because all or some parent keys haven't been defined yet, so you have to do something like:

```
mySecondObject = {};

mySecondObject.property1 = {};

mySecondObject.property1.value = {};

mySecondObject.property1.value.type = {};

mySecondObject.property1.value.type.price = "456"
```

Is there a method in JS that allows you to just declare an object with as many keys as you want and automatically creates all the parent keys? I couldn't find anything in Underscore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no (standard) function for doing this.

An alternate initialiser is this:

```
var mySecondObject = { property1: { value: { type: { price : "456" } } } };
```